# What is difference between php strip_tags and filter_var function?

Tags: php

They both seems to stripe out html,javascript tags. So when to use which?
I have tried both like

```
<?php

$user_input = "<script>alert('Your site sucks!');</script>";

echo strip_tags($user_input);

?>
```

And

```
<?php

$user_input = "<script>alert('Your site sucks!');</script>";

echo filter_var($user_input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);

?>
```

Comment: If you're trying to prevent XSS then you should use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` instead

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - that's for the output though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strip_tags()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) does just that. According to PHP documentation it:

> strips HTML and PHP tags from a string

[`filter_var()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) gives you a bit more to work with as you can use different filters with it i.e. FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL will sanitize the string to return a valid email.

In terms difference between `strip_tags` and `filter_var` with **FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED** specifically strip_tags will allow less than symbol and filter_var with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED will remove it.

I.e.:

```
strip_tags("testing < practice") will return "testing < practice"
filter_var("testing < practice", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED) will return "testing "
```

Comment: You should have added the filter's usage, which I edited. Some may not know how to use that, believe it or not ;-)

Answer (score 2):

strip_tags strictly filters all html and php tags from a given string.

filter_var filters out based on multiple different flags that you can provide.
It does not rectify a string, but it validates it instead

IE: if you use filter_var with flag: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, if you give it a valid email address, it will return it as it is, while an invalid email will return false

Answer (score 0):

Strip_tags allows you the option to define tags which you may want unstripped while filter_var sanitize doesn't.